# error: component 'clippy' for target {target} is unavailable for download

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustup

When using a custom `rust-toolchain` file with a pinned version

```
1.59.0
```

and running `cargo clippy` in `1.59.0`, I get

```
error: the 'cargo-clippy' binary, normally provided by the 'clippy' component, is not applicable to the '1.59.0-aarch64-apple-darwin' toolchain
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why does your title mention rustfmt but the error is for clippy?

Comment: I apologize the error can occur for any component . It’s the same fix.

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to `rustup` being corrupted. The surest way to fix this is reinstalling `rustup`

- `rustup self uninstall`
- Then reinstall it via [rustup.rs](https://rustup.rs/)